# In PowerShell, is it possible to send Out-File to $null?

Tags: powershell

I have implemented some benchmarks in a script. It simply outputs (each one may have some additional info so they aren't all identical):

```
Write-Output "Time to complete $secondselapsed" | Out-File -FilePath "$perflog" -Append
```

This is for my own purpose when testing. I have a dozen or so in my script measuring different performances. I don't want to have to comment them all out if I want to disable and then re-enabled them. Is there a way to just assign `$perflog` to some form of NULL?

Setting `$perflog=$null` just throws an error:

```
Out-File: Cannot bind argument to parameter 'FilePath' because it is an empty string.
```

I know `Out-Null` exists, but that doesn't seem to help much here either.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can't you wrap the code that you don't want to run on some conditions in something similar to a `#IF DEBUG` conditional compilation? You could define a simple `bool` variable, or use the `$DebugPreference` / `Write-Debug`, depending on the use case

Comment: Note that out-file -append can mix encodings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think simply using `>>` instead of `Out-File -Append` should be enough for your use-case

```
$perflog = '..\file\path.log'   

# you can comment\out this single line to switch between writing to file or sending to $null
$perflog = $null

Write-Output "Time to complete $secondselapsed" >> $perflog
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll give this a try. Seems simple. I used to do a lot of batch scripting so not sure why I didn't think of this! Also be easy to do a quick code replace `| Out-File -FilePath "$perflog" -Append` with `>> $perflog`

Comment: Probably because using a cmdlet to write content into files is a very Powershell thing compared to simply pipe content into them. You are thinking too much in Powershell :D. More generally, piping to files seems perfect in your specific use-case of small testing, but something more complex might require other solutions. Something I often used is writing simple functions encapsulating `Out-File` but including a script-wide set switch to enable the actual writing... which is basically how one is supposed to implement `-WhatIf` now i think about it

Answer (score 3):

Why not just skip calling `Out-File` entirely?

```
if ($perflog) {
    Write-Output "Time to complete $secondselapsed" | Out-File -FilePath "$perflog" -Append
}
```

Comment: For additional encapsulation, the OP could wrap the logging in a custom function like ```Write-MyLog “message” [-Debug | -Info | -Error]``` and then use a global logging level to control what level of messages are logged. Also makes it really easy to switch implementations at a later date without revisiting loads of ```Write-Output | Out-File``` commands littered around the codebase…